# Why the first element is not added createWriteStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I want to add files to the server so

```
uploadFiles: async (_, { files }) => {
      const x = await Promise.all(files);
      for (const [key, value] of x.entries()) {
        const { createReadStream, filename } = value;
        brduj.push(filename);
        createReadStream().pipe(
          createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, "../images", filename))
        );
      }
    }
```

but always the first item is not added. I do not understand why. How can this be fixed ?

Comment: What does `createReadStream()` do when it's not passed any arguments?

Comment: Add all files except the first.

Comment: You did not answer my question.  Please show the code for `createReadStream()`.  It does not make any sense that it does not accept any arguments.

Comment: I do not know, I took this example from the Internet. here all code.https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4TZg/4SoPr6vXE

Comment: If you want further help, then add YOUR code for `createReadStream()` to your question.  I tried looking at that link and couldn't find it and wasn't willing to download files to try to look for it (and that site isn't in English either).

Comment: Most likely what you want is: `fs = require('fs')` & `fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(...)`